# Get Max value with respected column values within multiple unique groups

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get all column in select statement with Max value

Here is my query

```
select city, 
       gender, 
       age_group,
       (count(id)/(select count(id) from table)) * 100 id_count_group_wise 
from table where state = 'true'
group by city, gender, age_group
order by city
```

Now above query will give me unique groups of `(city, gender, age_group)` with their respective `count`

How can I get the `Max of (id_count_group_wise )` out of above query (`where all records are already unique groups`) with `city, gender and age_group` in select output?

Comment: Give table creation and insert statements, and the expected output

Comment: What's the version of your database?

Comment: database version 19C

Comment: @OxanaGrey Can you Write Down Result You want in Example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use analytic function `max` applied to your calculation:

> ```
> create table t as
> select
>   level as id,
>   'City ' || mod(level, 5) as city,
>   decode(mod(level, 2), 1, 'M', 'F') as gender,
>   30 + mod(level, 4) as age_group,
>   case
>     when level > 30
>     then 'false'
>     else 'true'
>   end as state
> from dual
> connect by level < 40
> ```

> ```
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/
>   city, 
>   gender, 
>   age_group,
>   trunc(count(id)/cnt.cnt * 100, 3) id_count_group_wise,
>   trunc(max(count(id)/cnt.cnt) over() * 100, 3) as max_
> from t
>   cross join (
>     select count(id) as cnt
>     from t
>   ) cnt
> where state = 'true'
> group by city, gender, age_group, cnt.cnt
> order by city
> ```
>
> ```
> CITY   | GENDER | AGE_GROUP | ID_COUNT_GROUP_WISE |  MAX_
> :----- | :----- | --------: | ------------------: | ----:
> City 0 | F      |        30 |               2.564 | 5.128
> City 0 | F      |        32 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 0 | M      |        31 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 0 | M      |        33 |               2.564 | 5.128
> City 1 | F      |        30 |               2.564 | 5.128
> City 1 | F      |        32 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 1 | M      |        31 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 1 | M      |        33 |               2.564 | 5.128
> City 2 | F      |        30 |               2.564 | 5.128
> City 2 | F      |        32 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 2 | M      |        31 |               2.564 | 5.128
> City 2 | M      |        33 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 3 | F      |        30 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 3 | F      |        32 |               2.564 | 5.128
> City 3 | M      |        31 |               2.564 | 5.128
> City 3 | M      |        33 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 4 | F      |        30 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 4 | F      |        32 |               2.564 | 5.128
> City 4 | M      |        31 |               5.128 | 5.128
> City 4 | M      |        33 |               2.564 | 5.128
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=007a997de0f847dda3fe62d4f5b6125e)*

Answer (score 0):

Like this For Every Group

```
select city, 
       gender, 
       age_group,max(id_count_group_wise) as clmcount from (
select city, 
       gender, 
       age_group,
       (count(id)/(select count(id) from table)) * 100 id_count_group_wise 
from table where state = 'true'
group by city, gender, age_group

)a
group by city, gender, age_group
order by city
```

Like this For all Group

```
select city, 
       gender, 
       age_group,max(id_count_group_wise) over(order by age_group)  as clmcount from (
select city, 
       gender, 
       age_group,
       (count(id)/(select count(id) from table)) * 100 id_count_group_wise 
from table where state = 'true'
group by city, gender, age_group

)a
order by city
```

In `order by` you want related column replace

Comment: it will give you max of every group. Need max out of all groups

Comment: @OxanaGrey Please check this it's ok for your query ?

Answer (score 0):

If the version of your DBMS is atleast `12c`, then just use `FETCH...ROW[S]` clause such as

```sql
SELECT city,
       gender,
       age_group,
       (COUNT(id) / (SELECT count(id) FROM table)) * 100 id_count_group_wise
  FROM t
 WHERE state = 'true'
 GROUP BY city, gender, age_group
 ORDER BY id_count_group_wise DESC
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY -- or replace ONLY with "WITH TIES" 
                        -- if the equal max values should be included in the result set
```